# Appium :cucumber FAILED (DuplicateStepDefinitionException)

Tags: java, cucumber, build.gradle, appium-ios, cucumber-junit

Previously I was working with calabash and recently jumped on to Appium. I need some help on Appium-CI-Bamboo issue. The Automation scripts were written in Java-Junit using gradle in cucumber format. It's working fine locally but fails on Bamboo server with below error. I have tried installing all the gems on server(MAC) which were available on my local machine(MAC) but couldn't find where the issue is. Did anyone faced this issue and able to solve it, if so could you help me with the solution which could be a great favour please?

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

:clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 20.098 secs
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build
:runTags UP-TO-DATE
:generateReport UP-TO-DATE
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in com.project.qa.steps.HomeSteps.tap_on_favourites_icon() in file:/Users/admin/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/PIR-IQDU-JOB1/UITest/build/classes/test/ and com.project.qa.steps.HomeSteps.tap_on_favourites_icon() in file:/Users/admin/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/PIR-IQDU-JOB1/UITest/build/classes/test/
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue.addStepDefinition(RuntimeGlue.java:33)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:151)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
            at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
            at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
            at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
            at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    :cucumber FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
    > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 27.164 secs
```

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any chance the HomeSteps class is extending another step definition which contains the same conflicting method. Seems your step definition is being loaded twice.

Comment: @Grasshopper as you know when we run the code, it builds a folder with all same classes right,the error consider that classes as duplicate step definitions as you can see the folder flow "UITest/build/classes/test/"

Comment: got solved by removing InterruptedException on wait command.